# pycharm not showing output

Tags: python, output

Hi I am starting to learn Python. I had written a code using Pycharm platform about linear search. But I wasn't obtain the required output on the console. Kindly suggest where I went wrong in the code. 
Thanks!

```
def linsearch (num, arr):
    print("Number to be search is:", num)
    print("The given array is:", arr)
    pos = 0
    for index in range(len(arr)):
        if arr(index) == num:
            pos = index + 1
            print(num, "found at index", pos)
            break
    return pos

num = 25
arr = [10, 20, 65, 15, 25, 8]
```

Comment: you haven't called your linsearch method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
print(linsearch(num, arr))
```

At the end of your code.
You only defined (`def`)the function here.
Now you need to call it by just writing `linsearch(num,arr)`

```
def linsearch (num, arr):
    print("Number to be search is:", num)
    print("The given array is:", arr)
    pos = 0
    for index in range(len(arr)):
        if arr(index) == num:
            pos = index + 1
            print(num, "found at index", pos)
            break
    return pos

num = 25
arr = [10, 20, 65, 15, 25, 8]
print(linsearch(num,arg))
```

An alternative is to replace `return` with `print`. Then you only have to call the function like so: `linsearch(num,arr)` instead of `print(linsearch(num,arg))`

Comment: `return` is better though, because that allows you to call the function later, or store the returned value for later use.